# How to get second class from two available with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, attr

I need to get the second class from an element which has two different classes, so i try the `split` method but something is wrong, can u help me?

```
js_kp_main_list.find('li#kp_r_04').addClass('class_01 class_02');
setTimeout(function(){
    var class_two = js_kp_main_list.attr("class").split(' ')[2];
    console.log(class_two);
},20);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use className native JS:

```
js_kp_main_list[0].className.split(' ')[1]; // holds second class
```

---

EDIT: Another contrived example
http://jsfiddle.net/KqXmN/

HTML

```
<div id="mydiv" class="class1 class2"></div>
```

JS

```
var $mydiv = $('#mydiv');

//logs "class2"
console.log($mydiv[0].className.split(' ')[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Indexes start at `0` in JavaScript and you need to use the `className` attribute:

### HTML

```
<div id="test" class="foo bar"></div>
```

### JavaScript

```
var elem = document.getElementById('test');

var classes = elem.className.split(' ');
console.log(classes);

var firstClass = classes[0];
var secondClass = classes[1];
// ...
```

### JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/9Nu9G/

Comment: i have the same error 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined

Comment: Sorry, I did not catch that you were using the class attribute wrong. Use `className` instead. I fixed the answer.